# Qual é o melhor jeito de fazer um javascript com mensagens padronizadas?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de fazer algum script que me retornasse algo do tipo

```
MENSAGEM_SUCESSO = 'Registro inserido com sucesso';
MENSAGEM_ERRO = 'Problemas ao inserir o registro!';
```

Logo em alguma function chamar essas "constantes":

```
function Salvar() {
   // se salvou com sucesso
   Alerta(MENSAGEM_SUCESSO, 'Mensagem'); // função hipotetica que exibe um alert em bootstrap no html
}
```

Gostaria de parametrizar as mensagens em um arquivo `js`

O que é melhor? const? let? ou apenas um arquivo com strings.

Preciso de uma orientação.

Comment: Mas `const` não resolve o seu problema? Por que não?

Comment: Se resolve, qual é a dúvida? Não ficou claro o que você precisa saber. Se for só o "melhor jeito", poderá ser considerada como baseada em opiniões, pelo menos se você não listar todos os requisitos que a solução deve atender, nesse caso quem sabe dê para avaliar a melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melhor que isto, recomendo você criar métodos para representar suas mensagens.

Por exemplo:

```
function Sucesso(nomeRegistro){
  alert(`${nomeRegistro} inserido(a) com sucesso!`);
}

function Falha(nomeRegistro){
  alert(`Problemas ao inserir ${nomeRegistro}!`);
}

if (true) {
  Sucesso("Produto");
}
else {
  Falha("Produto");
}
```

Espero ter dado uma luz.